# bash script to output database backup name

Tags: mysql, bash

I have this bash script which is returning:

```
$ ./database.sh
.sql_01_23__09_33_27.db1
.sql_01_23__09_33_27.db2
```

here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
NOW=`date '+%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S'`;
user="user";
passwd="passwd";
host="localhost";
while IFS='' read -r db || [[ -n "$db" ]]; do
  f="$NOW";
  g="$db.$f";
  out="$g.sql"
  echo $out
  mysqldump --verbose --opt -u $user -p $passwd -h $host $db > $out
done < "../data/databases.csv"
```

the `out` variable for the name of the backup file is all reversed.

databases.csv is like

```
db1
db2
```

any advice is much appreciated

Comment: I just tried your script, and it worked fine for me

Comment: Is it possible that $db somehow contains newline characters?

Comment: I don't suppose you are in a RTL locale or anything interesting like that?

Comment: i am on a windows 10, using git bash

Comment: You are probably running another script than the one you pasted. The one you pasted here works fine and a.o. shows the `%Y` part of the date (2018) which is not in your output.